# Issue deploy python 3.4 app to bluemix using Wordnik

Tags: python, python-3.4, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am having an issue getting my Python 3.4.1 app up and running in Bluemix.  Here is my app.

When my app tries to start in Bluemix it never starts, it eventually says down.  Any ideas?

manifest.yml:

```
    ---
    applications:
    - name: myappname
      buildpack: python_buildpack
      instances: 1
      memory: 128M
```

Procfile:

```
web: python server.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.10.1
```

server.py:

```
"""Cloud Foundry test"""
from flask import Flask,request,render_template
import os

##########API DOESN"T WORK WHEN DEPLOYING TO BLUEMIX#######
from wordnik import *
apiUrl = 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4'
apiKey = 'myapikey'
client = swagger.ApiClient(apiKey, apiUrl)
 ##Call api to be used in WordApi
wordApi = WordApi.WordApi(client)


app = Flask(__name__)

if os.getenv("VCAP_APP_PORT"):
    port = int(os.getenv("VCAP_APP_PORT"))
else:
    port = 8080

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("firstForm.html")



@app.route("/main", methods=["POST"])

def ouch():
    return "Hello... World?"




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding wordnik to my requirements.txt file.  On Windows (my local machine) the dependency was installed, but in Bluemix it wasn't.  I needed to explicitly call out each dependency in my requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==0.10.1
wordnik-py3
```